# How to efficiently loop through date columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset where index for the columns have date format.  To explain my problem, i am building a similar dataset as below:

import pandas as pd

```
Cities = ['San Francisco', 'Los Angeles', 'New York', 'Huston', 'Chicago']
Jan = [10, 20, 15, 10, 35]
Feb = [12, 23, 17, 15, 41]
Mar = [15, 29, 21, 21, 53]
Apr = [27, 48, 56, 49, 73]

data = pd.DataFrame({'City': Cities, '01/01/20': Jan, '02/01/20': Feb, '03/01/20': Mar, '04/01/20': Apr})

print (data)

            City  01/01/20  02/01/20  03/01/20  04/01/20
0  San Francisco        10        12        15        27
1    Los Angeles        20        23        29        48
2       New York        15        17        21        56
3         Huston        10        15        21        49
4        Chicago        35        41        53        73
```

I want to plot the data for each city as a function of time.  Here is my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

cols = data.columns 

dates = data.loc[:, cols[1:]].columns

San_Francisco = []
Los_Angeles = []
New_York = []
Huston = []
Chicago = []

for i in dates:
    San_Francisco.append(data[data['City'] == 'San Francisco'][i].sum())
    Los_Angeles.append(data[data['City'] == 'Los Angeles'][i].sum())
    New_York.append(data[data['City'] == 'New York'][i].sum())
    Huston.append(data[data['City'] == 'Huston'][i].sum())
    Chicago.append(data[data['City'] == 'Chicago'][i].sum())
    
plt.plot(dates, San_Francisco, label='San Francisco')
plt.plot(dates, Los_Angeles, label='Los Angeles')
plt.plot(dates, New_York, label='New York')
plt.plot(dates, Huston, label='Huston')
plt.plot(dates, Chicago, label='Chicago')
plt.legend()
```

The results is what I want, however, for large dataset, my approach is not efficient.  How can I speed it up? Also for the plotting section, I have a large rows of cities and manually hardcoding the names is tedious; is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: this looks similar to `data.set_index("City").T.plot()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible some values of `City` are duplicated first aggregate by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), then transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last ploting by [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
data.groupby('City').sum().T.plot()
```

---

[image: graph]

If column `City` has always unique values is possible use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
data.set_index("City").T.plot()
```

EDIT:

```
df = data.groupby('City').sum().T
    
N = 10
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // N, axis=1).plot()
```

Comment: I guess we require `data.groupby('City').sum().T.plot()`

Comment: @jezrael & @ShubhamSharma; thanks; this saved me :)

Comment: In my real dataset, I have up to 300 cities but I want to plot 10 cities for each graph, how would I do that?

Comment: @A.E - So there should be multiple graphs?

Comment: @jezrael yes multiple graphs, each graph represents only 10 cities